# Error while Adding my ssh key to my github account

Tags: git, github, ssh, public-key

I'm new to git hub. Need help regarding generating and adding my ssh key to my GIT account from GIT shell on windows. could not find any question regarding the issue I'm having. So my problem is- 
I've completed till step 3 of [github help](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/) .

But while executing the step 4 I'm getting the following errors.

```
C:\Users\ashigope\Documents\GitHub> clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
At line:1 char:6
clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
+      ~
The '<' operator is reserved for future use.
At line:1 char:6
+ clip < ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
+      ~
+ CategoryInfo: ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : RedirectionNotSupported*
```

[image]

Kindly suggest me what should be done. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: whatever executes when you run "clip" seems to be something different compared to what the github tutorial expects

Comment: you can copy the key to clipbpard using any text editor like notepad++ as well.

Comment: Looks like you are in the wrong shell.

Comment: Actually I tried with this one: 
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip
& it finally worked. 

**Thank you** 
_[Thorbjorn Ravn Anderson](http://stackoverflow.com/users/53897/thorbj%c3%b8rn-ravn-andersen)_

Answer (score 0):

Simply follow those steps and you will set up your ssh key in no time:

- Generate a new ssh key (or skip this step if you already have a key)
  `ssh-keygen -t -rsa -C "your@email"`
- Once you have your key set in `home/.ssh` directory (or `Users/<your user>.ssh` under windows), open it and copy the content

---

#### How to add sh key to github account?

- Login to github account
- Click on the rancher on the top right (Settings)
  [image: github account settigns]
- Click on the `SSH keys`
  [image: ssh key section]
- Click on the `Add ssh key`
  [image: Add ssh key]
- Paste your key and save

Now you all set to go :-)

Comment: I worked with this one... is it okay? 
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | clip


Thanks for you tips. _[codeWizard](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1755598/codewizard)_

Comment: Yep its fine, you can use it

Comment: & thanks to you, I learned another new command for the same. :) Thank you.